# No attribute 'compile', how can I modify the class, so that it works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

The `neuMF` class is not a `Keras`'s class and therefore it doesn't provide any compile method.
I would better use `keras.Model` instead of `nn.Blocks`.

Unfortunately, I do not really understand what nn.Blocks is and how I could replace it in the class.
How should I modfy my code, so that it works with `keras.Model` and can use the `Keras` method?

Here is my code:

```
from d2l import mxnet as d2l
from mxnet import autograd, gluon, np, npx
from mxnet.gluon import nn
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


    class NeuMF(nn.Block):
        def init(self, num_factors, num_users, num_items, nums_hiddens,
                     kwargs):
            super(NeuMF, self).init(kwargs)
            self.P = nn.Embedding(num_users, num_factors)
            self.Q = nn.Embedding(num_items, num_factors)
            self.U = nn.Embedding(num_users, num_factors)
            self.V = nn.Embedding(num_items, num_factors)
            self.mlp = nn.Sequential()
            for num_hiddens in nums_hiddens:
                self.mlp.add(nn.Dense(num_hiddens, activation='relu',
                                      use_bias=True))
            self.prediction_layer = nn.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', use_bias=False)
    
        def forward(self, user_id, item_id):
            p_mf = self.P(user_id)
            q_mf = self.Q(item_id)
            gmf = p_mf * q_mf
            p_mlp = self.U(user_id)
            q_mlp = self.V(item_id)
            mlp = self.mlp(np.concatenate([p_mlp, q_mlp], axis=1))
            con_res = np.concatenate([gmf, mlp], axis=1)
            return self.prediction_layer(con_res)
    
    
    hidden = [5,5,5]
    
    model = NeuMF(5, num_users, num_items, hidden)
    model.compile(
         #loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
    )
```

And I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-5979072369bd> in <module>()
      2 
      3 model = NeuMF(5, num_users, num_items, hidden)
----> 4 model.compile(
      5      #loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
      6     loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),

AttributeError: 'NeuMF' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Edit:

I replaced `nn` to `layers`

```
class NeuMF(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_factors, num_users, num_items, nums_hiddens,
                 **kwargs):
        super(NeuMF, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.P = layers.Embedding(num_users, num_factors)
        self.Q = layers.Embedding(num_items, num_factors)
        self.U = layers.Embedding(num_users, num_factors)
        self.V = layers.Embedding(num_items, num_factors)
        self.mlp = layers.Sequential()
        for num_hiddens in nums_hiddens:
            self.mlp.add(layers.Dense(num_hiddens, activation='relu',
                                  use_bias=True))
        self.prediction_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', use_bias=False)

    def forward(self, user_id, item_id):
        p_mf = self.P(user_id)
        q_mf = self.Q(item_id)
        gmf = p_mf * q_mf
        p_mlp = self.U(user_id)
        q_mlp = self.V(item_id)
        mlp = self.mlp(np.concatenate([p_mlp, q_mlp], axis=1))
        con_res = np.concatenate([gmf, mlp], axis=1)
        return self.prediction_layer(con_res)
```

Then I got an new error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7e09b0f80300> in <module>()
      1 hidden = [1,1,1]
      2 
----> 3 model = NeuMF(1, num_users, num_items, hidden)
      4 model.compile(
      5      #loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/embeddings.py in __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer, embeddings_regularizer, activity_regularizer, embeddings_constraint, mask_zero, input_length, **kwargs)
    102       else:
    103         kwargs['input_shape'] = (None,)
--> 104     if input_dim <= 0 or output_dim <= 0:
    105       raise ValueError('Both `input_dim` and `output_dim` should be positive, '
    106                        'found input_dim {} and output_dim {}'.format(

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Well, what do you *want to happen* when you use the method? Now, read the documentation for the class. Does it describe a way to do what you want? Maybe it happens automatically? Or maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the quick comment! The class NeuMF can be found here https://d2l.ai/chapter_recommender-systems/neumf.html.
I would like to work with `Keras.Model` so that I can use the compile method and practice compiling the model.
Unfortunately, I don't have a really good description of the model, hence the question.

Comment: Pleas always provide all necessary ``import``-statements.

Comment: I changed all `nn` to `layers`. For example `nn.Embedding` to `layers.Embedding`. About now I get this error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: There is a lot going on in your ``import``-statements. You are overwriting ``import numpy as np`` with ``from mxnet import np``. Also, never include ``pip``-commands in your code; install those packagase separately and then ``import`` them properly. Again, please only add all **necessary** ``import``-statements. Half of what you added now is not relevant to this question.

Comment: If you made changes to your code, please also update your post.

Comment: @Alperino thanks! I edited it. Please have a look.

Comment: The first and second argument of ``tf.keras.layers.Embedding`` are supposed to be input- and output-dimensions, thus integers, see [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/). You have not provided your values for ``num_factors``, ``num_users``, ``num_items``, ``nums_hiddens``, but the error suggests that you did not choose integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After already quite some discussion in the comments, there are still several problems with your code and clarification needed from your side:

1. subclasses of `keras.Model` should implement the `__call__` method, but not a `forward` method.
2. you can't just build `numpy`-operations like `np.concatenate` inside your model, always use `keras`-layers like `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate`.
3. as already commented, the error you've posted most likely comes from `num_factors`, `num_users`, `num_items` not being integer, though I can only guess here, since you did not provide those to us.
4. also, I can currently only guess what you are trying to achieve, since this is not at all clear from what you posted.

Let us approach the issues in a different way. The following code snippet runs without error and might be a good starting point for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class NeuMF(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_factors, num_users, num_items, nums_hiddens,
                 **kwargs):
        super(NeuMF, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.P = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_users, num_factors)
        self.Q = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_items, num_factors)
        self.U = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_users, num_factors)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_items, num_factors)
        self.mlp = tf.keras.Sequential()
        for num_hiddens in nums_hiddens:
            self.mlp.add(
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                    num_hiddens,
                    activation='relu',
                    use_bias=True
                    )
                )
        self.prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', use_bias=False)

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        x  = self.P(inputs[0])
        x1 = self.Q(inputs[1])
        x  = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([x,x1])

        y = self.U(inputs[0])
        y1 = self.V(inputs[1])
        y = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([y,y1])
        y = self.mlp(y)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x,y])
        return self.prediction_layer(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #replace these with values of your choice:
    num_factors = 2
    num_users   = 3
    num_items   = 4 
    nums_hidden = [5,5,5]

    model = NeuMF(num_users, num_items, num_items, nums_hidden)
    model.compile(
        loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
        )
```